# Feature Selection Using Custom Python Expression Functions in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select, qgis-custom-function

I'd like to write an expression function in QGIS 2.18 to select features based on the value of their attributes. How can I access attribute values within my function?

I have noticed that in QGIS 2.18.x, the selection does not seem to work when accessing feature attributes as `feature['attribute']`.

For example, I tried the following functions to select features from Natural Earth's [Populated Places Simple](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/) dataset. The three functions below select all the capital cities in QGIS 2.14.12, but no features are selected in QGIS 2.18.7.

```
@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def select_country_capitals_1(value1, feature, parent):
    """ Select all the capital cities """
    return feature['featurecla'] == 'Admin-0 capital'

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def select_country_capitals_2(value1, feature, parent):
    return feature[3] == 'Admin-0 capital'

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def select_country_capitals_3(value1, feature, parent):
    return feature.attributes()[3] == 'Admin-0 capital'
```

Agreed that the above is possible with a simple query `"featurecla" = 'Admin-0 capital'` from the expression engine, but I would like to access attribute values within the function and perform some further computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess some things have changed since QGIS 2.14 but the following should work for QGIS 2.18:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def select_country_capitals_1(value, feature, parent):
    """ Select all the capital cities """
    if feature.attributes()[3] == 'Admin-0 capital':
        return value
```

Then use the following expression to call the function:

```
select_country_capitals_1("featurecla")
```

Where `"featurecla"` is your field name.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to include multiple fields in your expression, you could add another parameter in your function and use the logical operator `and` in your `if` statement to add another condition. For example, if we want to select all attributes which has the value `Admin-0 capital` in the *"featurecla"* field **AND** has a _"pop_max_" greater than `10000` then we could use:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def select_country_capitals_1(field1, field2, feature, parent):
    """ Select all the capital cities """
    if feature.attributes()[0] == 'Admin-0 capital' and feature.attributes()[1] > 10000:
        return field1
```

And call this using:

```
select_country_capitals("featurecla", "pop_max")
```

*Note: the code assumes the fields "featurecla" and "pop_max" have a field index of 0 and 1 respectively.*

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks a lot for your answer. It works. Could you also help me with the case when I want to use multiple feature attributes within my function? For example if I need the fields "featurecla" and "pop_max", will the function then be called as `select_country_capitals("featurecla", "pop_max")`? I tried that but am getting a Parser error, `select_country_capitals() is called with the wrong number of arguments.` I should probably also let you know that following your code, I set `args='auto'` in the qgsfunction decorator, but I still get the error.

Comment: @Simran - Most welcome, glad it worked! Edited my post to include a possible method to use two fields :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to access feature attributes within expression functions in QGIS 2.18 would be to specify them in referenced_columns within the @qgsfunction decorator.

For example, the function should be modified as below, and can be called as `select_country_capitals()`

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=['featurecla'])
def select_country_capitals(feature, parent):
    """ Select all the capital cities """
    if feature['featurecla'] == 'Admin-0 capital':
        return value
```